# encoding chinese characters for url in php

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, decoding

So I have a bunch of urls and some of them have chinese characters in them like this:
`http://www.abcdefg.com/ad2/zh/profile/2169358/1/冰绿茶/`

However I need to process all of these urls and encode the urls with the chinese characters in them into something like this:
`http://www.abcdefg.com/ad2/zh/profile/2169358/1/%E4%BA%8C%E4%B8%8D%E4%BA%8C%E7%9A%84%E4%BA%8C/`

So the chinese part must be encoded in php.

I tried using `urlencode`, `rawurlencode` but none worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note: The encoded urls are meant to be stored not displayed by the browser so changing the header is not an option.

Comment: sorry i wasn't clear. The encoded url is not used for the browser to display so changing the header won't work.

Comment: Can you show example of your code? It's not clear from where original urls come from.

Comment: the original urls are stored in file so there isn't too much for me to show. 
I just want to process them and store the encoded urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case, you may wish to use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to separate the URL components and only `urlencode()` the `path` and `query` components.

```
$url = 'http://www.abcdefg.com/ad2/zh/profile/2169358/1/冰绿茶/';
$parsed = parse_url($url);

print_r($parsed);
```

You would get

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.abcdefg.com
    [path] => /ad2/zh/profile/2169358/1/冰绿茶
)
```

so, `urlencode()` `path` and `query` (if any).

Once those are URL-encoded, you will need to reassemble back so that `scheme` (http), `host`(www.abcdefg.com) remain unaffected.

If you still prefer to have `/` intact, `explode()` the `path` first before URLencoding it.

```
$pathComponents = explode('/', $parsed['path']);

$pathComponents = array_map('urlencode', $pathComponents);

// Assemble back $path
$path = implode('/', $pathComponents);
```

Comment: So I tried this method too but urlecode also encodes the '/', which is not what I want.

Comment: Add another step to `url_parse()`, `explode()` the path first.